# Running bat command on certain file type

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I'm trying to execute a command in a bat file which is working perfect when I specify the targeted file in the command ( for example: "c:\my work\month.stats.txt").

The command line structure is exactly like this

```
 xxxxxxx.exe [command_parameter] c:\my work\month.stats.txt
```

I want to make it work automatically on every ".txt" file exist in certain folder (for example: "c:\my work" folder).

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: it's a command linked to an exe file related to my work. 
it's working like this 

( xxxxxxx.exe [command_parameter] c:\my work\month.stats.txt ).

The thing is that I have many ".txt" files and I want the bat file to do this command on any .txt file exist on "c:\my work" folder

Comment: would you please give me an example for this command line?

( xxxxxxx.exe [command_parameter] c:\my work\month.stats.txt)

Comment: Open command prompt in that folder and type: `For /R %Y in (*.txt)  do (xxx.exe %Y)`

Comment: `forfiles /s /m *.txt /p c:\"my work" /C "cmd /c xxxx.exe xxx_params @path"` no need any bat files, that one line can do what you want

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. I really appreciate it. 

I tried both commands and they worked. 
The thing is that "xxxx.exe" file execute commands by itself and the final parameter of this command is the path of the text file. When I use "For" or "forfiles" commands they work only if the "exe" and it's associated files exist at the same path of the targeted ".txt" files. I'm looking for a way to make it work even if the targeted ".txt" in another path. THANKS AGAIN.

Answer (score 1):

To apply the executable command with all text file use `For /R` loop. Open command prompt in that folder and type:

```bat
For /R %Y in (*.txt) do (abc.exe %Y)
```

Or if you want to apply the command in another folder add the folder path in that command:

```bat
For /R "C:\path\folder" %Y in (*.txt) do (abc.exe %Y)
```

Here are the details of this command:

> - Syntax:
>
> ```
> FOR /R [[drive:]path] %%parameter IN (set) DO command
> ```
>
> - Key drive:
>
>   - path : The folder tree where the files are located.
>   - set : A set of one or more files. Wildcards must be used. If (set) is a period character (.) then FOR will loop through every folder.
>   - command : The command(s) to carry out, including any command-line parameters.
>   - %%parameter : A replaceable parameter: in a batch file use %%G (on the command line %G)

Source: [ss64: For /R](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)